# How to generate Map file using cmake

Tags: assembly, cmake, stm32, ld, elf

I am trying to cross-compile, host is wondows target is stm32(arm). I am trying to generate a map file from the arm-none-eabi-ld.
My issues are twofold

1. I am unable to generate a Map file. This is my primary problem.
2. When I run build clean my .hex file & .bin files are not deleted.

Please find my toolchain cmake file below(arm-none-eabi.cmake).

> ```
> MESSAGE("Running : arm-none-eabi.cmake")
>
> SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR  arm)
> SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME       Generic)
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS  TRUE)
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS  TRUE)
>
> SET(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGTE_TYPE   STATIC_LIBRARY)
>
> SET(TARGET      STM32F030x4)
> SET(ARCH        armv6-m)
> SET(CPU         cortex-m0)
> SET(ARM_ISA     mthumb)
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    arm-none-eabi-gcc)
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-g++)
> SET(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-g++)
> SET(CMAKE_SIZE          arm-none-eabi-size)
> SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP       arm-none-eabi-objdump)
> SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY       arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
>
> SET(OPTIMISATION Og)
> SET(DEBUG "ggdb")
>
> SET(CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS  "-march=${ARCH} -mcpu=${CPU} -${ARM_ISA} -D${TARGET} -${OPTIMISATION} -${DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-builtin --specs=nosys.specs -lc --entry main")
> SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS}")
> SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS       "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} ") #-std=gnull
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wno-volatile -std=c++1z")
> SET(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_COMMON_FLAGS} -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,\"${TARGET}.map\"  --specs-nosys.specs")
> ```

-Wl,-Map,"${TARGET}.map" command is not generating a map file.

My CmakeLists.txt file

> ```
> CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.20)
>
> INCLUDE("CMake/arm-none-eabi.cmake")
>
> SET(CMAKE_C_STANDARD    11)
> SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD  17)
>
>
>
> PROJECT(BLINKY VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "Blinky Example")
> MESSAGE("Building "${PROJECT_NAME})
>
> FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
>     LDSCRIPTS
>     "ldscripts/*.ld"
> )
>
> FOREACH(file ${LDSCRIPTS})
>     SET(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CAMKE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T \"${file}\" ")
> ENDFOREACH()
>
> #Setup project headers
> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
>     "Core/"
>     "Drivers/"
> )
>
> #Setup porject sources
> FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
>     APPLICATION_SOURCE
>     "Application/*.c"
>     "Application/*.cpp"
>     "Application/*.s"
>     "Core/*.c"
>     "Core/*cpp"
>     "Core/*.s"
>     "Drivers/*.c"
>     "Drivers/*.cpp"
>     "Drivers/*.s"
> )
>
> ADD_EXECUTABLE(${TARGET}.elf ${APPLICATION_SOURCE})
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}.bin ALL DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.bin)
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}.hex ALL DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.hex)
> ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(SIZE ALL ${CMAKE_SIZE} ${TARGET}.elf DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

For the other question, you should do something like this...

```
add_executable(foo ...)

target_link_options(foo
  PUBLIC
    LINKER:-Map=foo.map
)
```

This is discussed in the section `Handling Compiler Driver Differences` [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html).

Answer (score 0):

(I believe general guidance is one issue/question per posted question)

answer for:

> When I run build clean my .hex file & .bin files are not deleted.

Per the docs for [add_custom_target()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

> The target has no output file

Having no output file means that CMake doesn't know what it produces.  What you probably want to do is use [add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html), and then make the custom target depend on the custom command:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${TARGET}.bin DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.bin)
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${TARGET}.hex DEPENDS ${TARGET}.elf COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex ${TARGET}.elf ${TARGET}.hex)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}_bin DEPENDS ${TARGET}.bin)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(${TARGET}_hex DEPENDS ${TARGET}.hex)
```

I'm not sure if the `${TARGET}.bin` would collide, but I modified it to reduce ambiguity for future maintainers.